# Como importar un módulo dentro de otro modulo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importación, modulos

Buen día quería saber si es posible importar un modulo que dentro de su codigo tenga escrito que importa otro modulo o si eso no es posible o existe una manera:
Ejemplo:
Tengo el siguiente esquema

```
CARPETA 1
-->_intit__.py
-->_codigo_carpeta1.py
-->CARPETA 2
        -->_intit__.py
        -->_codigo_carpeta2.py
        -->CARPETA 3
                -->_intit__.py
                -->_codigo_carpeta3.py
```

ahora bien en la carpeta 3 hay un clase llamada Padre1()
CARPETA 3

```
class Padre1():
    
    def impresionPadre1(self):
    print("Estoy imprimiendo desde PADRE 1 CARPETA 3")

imprimir=Padre1()
imprimir.impresionPadre1()
```

dentro de la carpeta 2 creo una clase hija de la carpeta 3

```
from prueba3.prueba3 import *

class Padre2(Padre1):

    def impresionPadre2(self):
    print("Estoy imprimiendo desde PADRE 2 CARPETA 2")

imprimir2=Padre2()
imprimir2.impresionPadre2()
imprimir2.impresionPadre1()
```

hasta aqui todo bien el archivo funciona pero cuando quiero hacer la tercera ya no

```
from prueba2.prueba3.prueba3 import *
from prueba2.prueba2 import *

class Padre3(Padre2):

    def impresionPadre3(self):
    print("Estoy imprimiendo desde PADRE 3 CARPETA 1")

imprimir3=Padre3()
imprimir3.imprisionPadre3()
imprimir3.impresionPadre2()
imprimir3.impresionPadre1()
```

pero aquí me da un error me dice que no encuentra el modulo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emili\Desktop\ERP\module\prueba1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from prueba2.prueba2 import *
  File "C:\Users\emili\Desktop\ERP\module\prueba2\prueba2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from prueba3.prueba3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prueba3'
[Finished in 299ms]
```

ya probe tambien en el ultimo archivo dejando solamente, pero me da el mismo erro

```
from prueba2.prueba2 import *

class Padre3(Padre2):

    def impresionPadre3(self):
    print("Estoy imprimiendo desde PADRE 3 CARPETA 1")

imprimir3=Padre3()
imprimir3.imprisionPadre3()
imprimir3.impresionPadre2()
imprimir3.impresionPadre1()
```

Comment: Hola, Emilio. Para darte una respuesta, deberías poner exactamente el nombre de las carpetas y ficheros en el esquema de carpetas. Supongo que los ficheros `_intit__.py` se llaman realmente `__init__.py`. Es importante que tengan ese nombre. Así mismo, el nombre de la carpeta será el nombre del paquete de dónde importar el módulo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya lo solucione pero no entiendo por qué. Lo que hice fue cambiar la importacion de la carpeta 2, si alguien me puede explicar

```
from prueba2.prueba3.prueba3 import *  #(Solo la puse como si la llamara desde la carpeta 1, no entiendo porque pero funciona)


class Padre2(Padre1):

    def impresionPadre2(self):
        print("Estoy imprimiendo desde PADRE 2 CARPETA 2")

imprimir2=Padre2()
imprimir2.impresionPadre2()
imprimir2.impresionPadre1()
```

Comment: Si la pregunta que ya hiciste está respondida puedes marcar la respuesta. Si ahora tu pregunta es otra, considera editar la que ya has hecho o hacer una nueva.

Comment: ve mira la razon por la cual estta asi es algo sque se me paso por alto

Comment: ve mira la razon por la cual estta asi es algo sque se me paso por alto resulta que from prueba2.prueba3 hace referencia a tus carpetas y preuba3 me imagino que asi declaraste el nombre del archivo como prueba3.py  en cuanto a laparte del import  * significa que vaa importar todod de to modulo en este caso prueba3.py portodo me refieor a funciones clases variables

Answer (score 0):

Mira los modulos en python segun la documentacion oficial menciona pueden importarse de la siguiente manera

```
import nombre_de_tu_modulo
```

sin mebargo estea forma de importar solo funciona si el modulo esta dentor de la misma carpeta
si quisieras importar desde otra carpeta diferente tednrias que hace ralgo como

```
from nombre_de_tu_modulo import nombre_de_lo_aue quieres importar vairable funcion clase
```

perode igual manera solo funciona si el modulo estadentro de la misma ruta supongamos que tu modulo se llamara conexion y esta dentro de la ruta por decir un ejemplo  DOcumentos/  adems de tener dentro de ese modulo conexion  una funcion llamada saludar  entonces en ese caso tendrias que hacer lo siguiente

```
from conexion import saludar
```

Pero aqui hay un problema y es que desde el primcipio estas dentro de la misma ruta si quisieras importar tu modulo dentro de otra ruta por ejemplo que ahora la ruta fuera /Documentos/Carpeta_1 entonces tendrias que hacer lo siguiente

```
from Carpeta_1.conexion import saludar
```

Como puedes ver ahora ya cambiaron las cosas ya que el modulo esta ahora dentro de otra ruta diferente
Para tu ejemplo tendrias que hacer lo siguiente
from nombre_dela_carpeta_1.nombre_dela_carpeta_2 import Nombre_de_tu_modulo
osea

```
from prueba2.prueba3 import Padre1
```

Eso deberia de funcionar suerte amigo